# Magnetic field in straight wire with complex geometry

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I´m trying to understand how to calculate the magnetic field as announced in this question.

Calculate the law of Ampere and Biot Savart the magnetic field B due to a current I in an infinite straight wire at a point P a distance R from the wire. Demonstrate by Bio Savart law that part of the wire to the left contributes to B / 2.[image]

I suppose that in the semicircular path of the wire I can use the example of this [PDF](http://physics.drexel.edu/~wking/courses/phys102_sum09/doc/rec/rec9_solutions.pdf) I mean the problem 28.20. This problem it was taken from this [book](http://pt.slideshare.net/MoniseSousa/fisica-basica-vol-3-moyses-nussenzveig-1ed-eletromagnetismo)
Unfortunately I don´t know how to proceed in the entire problem.

May I use the example of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TFen0yaChc) to calculate the other "x" and "z" axis?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to compute using the Biot-Savart law, calculate the magnetic field due to half an infinite wire, i.e, a wire starting from some point and extending upto infinity in some direction. This exercise is very useful and after doing it, you will have 2/3rd of the problem solved.(notice that there are two such wires)

Secondly using the example of the semi circle as in your pdf find out the magnetic field. Now at any point P, perform a vector addition of these three and get your result.

Comment: this is my doubt. Where I will put this point?

Comment: The point P is where you need to calculate your magnetic field. You have not specified in the question where P is supposed to be. Maybe the question might have P on the x axis. If it doesn't, then start with P on the x axis, for it is easier to solve for as seen from the symmetry of the problem.